# Garmin .fit file timestamp

Tags: c, embedded, garmin

I'm hoping someone can put me on the right path.  I'm developing an embedded project that will use the fitSDK.  One of the fields in the .fit file is the timestamp.

The only valid timestamp for the fit file is a uint32_t that is seconds since UTC 00:00 Dec 31 1989.

Since they aren't using epoch time, this could turn into something ugly....unless I'm totally overlooking something (very possible).

code snippets and or links to good information are welcome.

Comment: So what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 2):

I used the fit sdk and found that I could initialise a LapMesg by adding 631234800 to the start as in this C# extension method

```
public static DateTime SecondsSince1989ToDateTime(this int value)
{
    DateTime baseDate = new DateTime(1989, 12, 31, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    var dateAdjusted = baseDate.AddSeconds(value);
    return dateAdjusted;
}
```

For subsequent RecordMesg points I calculated the distance from the previous point to the current point and then added that time onto the start time, so this would be incremented at each point

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this issue was to find out what the EPOC timestamp of UTC 00:00 Dec 31 1989 was and use that as a constant.  We then populated current UTC from GPS data and applied the mktime() function and then it was just subtraction.
Code snippet as follows:

```
// utyear is two digits and tm_year is since 1900
utc_time.tm_year = pxFSTGPSrecord->utyear + 100;
utc_time.tm_mon = pxFSTGPSrecord->utmonth-1;
utc_time.tm_mday = pxFSTGPSrecord->utday;
utc_time.tm_hour = pxFSTGPSrecord->utch;
utc_time.tm_min = pxFSTGPSrecord->utcm;
utc_time.tm_sec = pxFSTGPSrecord->utcs;
utc_time.tm_isdst = 0;
utc_timestamp = mktime(&utc_time);
fit_timestamp = utc_timestamp - EPOC_TIMESTAMP;
```