# read a .fit file on Linux

Tags: converters, fit-protocol

How could I read Garmin's .fit file on Linux. I'd like to use it for some data analysis but the file is a binary file.

I have visited http://garmin.kiesewetter.nl/ but the website does not seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can use GPSbabel to do this. It's a command-line tool, so you end up with something like:

```
gpsbabel -i garmin_fit -f {filename}.fit -o csv -F {output filename}.csv
```

and you'll get a text file with all the lat/long coordinates.
What's trickier is getting out other data, ie: if you want speed, time, or other information from the .fit file. You can easily get those into a .gpx, where they're in xml and human-readable, but I haven't yet found a single line solution for getting that data into a csv.

Comment: Specifying -o unicsv adds altitude, date and time.  You can compute the velocity from these data.

Comment: With `-o unicsv` instead of `-o csv` in the command from the answer, I get a file which contains only the text: `No,Latitude,Longitude`.

Comment: With `-o gpx` I get better results: the gpx file created can then be opened using gpxviewer. On linux `sudo apt-get install gpxviewer`. [This](https://www.gpsbabel.org/capabilities.html) page is useful regarding the capabilities of gpsbabel with different formats.

Answer (score 7):

The company that created ANT made an SDK package available here:

https://www.thisisant.com/resources/fit

When unzipping this, there is a java/FitCSVTool.jar file. Then:

```
java -jar java/FitCSVTool.jar -b input.fit output.csv
```

I tested with a couple of files and it seems to work really well. Then of course the format of the csv can be a little bit complex.

For example, latitude and longitude are stored in semicircles, so it should be multiplied by 180/(2^31) to give GPS coordinates.

Comment: That link didn't give me the `.jar` file mentioned. This link did: https://www.thisisant.com/developer/resources/software-tools/ And it worked! But yeah, the output CSV file is pretty hard to read...

Comment: You can download the official sdk from Garmin now and use it with the command above: https://developer.garmin.com/fit/download/

Answer (score 1):

This page parses the file and lets you download it as tables. https://www.fitfileviewer.com/ The fun bit is converting the timestamps from numbers to readable timestamps [Garmin .fit file timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071406/garmin-fit-file-timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the file to a .csv, the Garmin repair tool at http://garmin.kiesewetter.nl/ will do this for you. I've just loaded the site fine, try again it may have been temporarily down.

To add a little more detail:

"FIT or Flexible and Interoperable Data Transfer is a file format used for GPS tracks and routes. It is used by newer Garmin fitness GPS devices, including the Edge and Forerunner." From the OpenStreetMap Wiki http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/FIT

There are many tools to convert these files to other formats for different uses, which one you choose depends on the use. GPSBabel is another converer tool that may help. gpsbabel.org (I can't post two links yet :)

Comment: Links to potential solutions are always welcome, but please add some details for future visitors in case link gets removed.

Comment: Thanks - the link works fine it is the online tool itself that does not seem to work. I have contacted the developer

Comment: I see, maybe try GPSBabel in the mean time, there are other tools available but some require payment.